# gmail API auth URI mismatch

Tags: python, gmail

I am trying to do auth to gmail and receiving an error URI mismatch.

```py
def gmail_authenticate():
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(credentials_path, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    # Build the Gmail service, Connect to the Gmail API
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    return service`
```

In the code above,
when calling the function in the test
`gmail_authenticate()`
receive the error URI mismatch code 404
I've added the URI to user mail console

[image]

Tried to authenticate gmail API but received an error URI mismatch.

Comment: Please post the full error message

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have followed the [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/postmaster/quickstart/python) Which tells you to create a desktop app credentails

[image]

You have mistakenly created web app credentials. Delete those and go create desktop credentials and it should work just fine.